# ¿Qué valor devuelve una query de pdo en php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

quería saber qué valor devuelve el siguiente código, porque he tenido problemas al recibir el valor, los cuales me dicen que no puede convertirse en string.

```html
<?php
try{
          $query = connect()->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET privileges = :priv WHERE user = :user");
            $query->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':priv', $priv, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $query->execute();
            #$result = $query->fetchAll();
            return $query;
        }catch (PDOException $e) {
            return 'Connection Failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
<?
```

Comment: Falta un poco más de contexto para poder ayudarte. Por ejemplo qué valores están recibiendo las variables $user y $priv, qué contiene la tabla usuarios, cuál es el mensaje exacto que te devuelve la base de datos, etc.

Comment: Lo que hace el código es ejecutar una consulta de actualización de SQL, actualizas el campo privileges de la tabla usuarios en función del usuario que se haya indicado en user.

Comment: Sí, como dice David es lo que quiero hacer en la consulta, pero quiero saber cual es el valor que devolvería dicha consulta, si un boolean, string, o qué, porque al ejecutarla me saca un error de sintaxis por dicha consulta, la cual al ver varios ejemplos, está bien.

Comment: Al hacer un `return $query;` lo que devuelve es el resultado del método `prepare`, porque `$query = connect()->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET privileges = :priv WHERE user = :user");`. Si lees la doc, te dice que `prepare` devuelve: **Si el servidor de la base de datos prepara con éxito la sentencia, PDO::prepare() devuelve un objeto PDOStatement. Si no es posible, PDO::prepare() devuelve FALSE o emite una excepción PDOException (dependiendo del manejo de errores).**

Comment: Muchas gracias Cedano, me quedó claro, por casualidad no tienes documentación sobre lo que nombraste como PDO::prepare y demás, o en la página de PHP está todo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al hacer un `return $query;` lo que devuelve es el resultado del método `prepare`, porque así tienes definida tu variable:

```
$query = connect()->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET privileges = :priv WHERE user = :user");
```

Si lees la doc, te dice lo siguiente sobre lo que `prepare` devuelve:

> #### Valores devueltos
>
> Si el servidor de la base de datos prepara con éxito la sentencia,
>   PDO::prepare() devuelve un objeto PDOStatement. Si no es posible,
>   PDO::prepare() devuelve FALSE o emite una excepción PDOException
>   (dependiendo del manejo de errores).
>
> <sub>[`prepare` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php)</sub>

Siendo que es una consulta del tipo `UPDATE` quizá te interese devolver la cantidad de filas actualizadas, o cero, en caso de que no haya actualizaciones o en caso de que la consulta falle.

Algo así:

```
try{
        $query="UPDATE usuarios SET privileges = :priv WHERE user = :user";
        $stmt = connect()->prepare($query);
        $arrParams=array(':user'=>$user, ':priv'=>$priv);
        $update=$stmt->execute($arrParams);

        /*Usamos un operador ternario para evaluar lo ocurrido*/
        $intResultado = ($update) ? $stmt->rowCount() : 0;
        return $intResultado;

        }catch (PDOException $e) {
            return 'Connection Failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Observa que he modificado el código, que no he usado los bind, porque **en PDO se pueden pasar los parámetros en el `execute`**, o sea, usar bind no es necesario aquí.

Si fuese una consulta del tipo `SELECT`, entonces te interesará devolver los datos que trae dicha consulta, usando uno de los métodos `fetch` de que dispone PDO.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedó claro todo.

Comment: @Astaroth línea 4, después de `try...`

Comment: Puede no importar, pero no me deja marcar como útil la respuesta :(

Comment: Necesitas algo de reputación para *votar a favor*. Creo que la acción se registra y será efectiva en cuanto tengas reputación suficiente. Si no, cuando tengas la reputación requerida podrás volver para ejercer tu voto a favor. Si mal no recuerdo, debes tener al menos 25 puntos como mínimo, los conseguirás pronto :).

Comment: Gracias nuevamente.